# Is detaching and reattching events needed when setting a BindingList

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I have the following code:

```
    private BindingList<Box> _boxesToDisplay;
    public BindingList<Box> BoxesToDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return _boxesToDisplay;
        }
        set 
        {
            // Unhook the old one.  Just incase
            _boxesToDisplay.AddingNew -= NewItemAdded;
            // Set the new value
            _boxesToDisplay = value;
            // Hook in the value again.
            _boxesToDisplay.AddingNew += NewItemAdded;
        }
    }
```

But I got to thinking.  It would be best if this was an overload for the assingment operator.  Then I got to wondering if they actually did that and I could just replace my code with this:

```
     public BindingList<Box> BoxesToDisplay { get; set; }
```

Is true?  Would this:

```
     myClass.BoxesToDisplay = new BindingList<Box>();
```

still have the `AddingNew` event set to `NewItemAdded()` with either definition of `BoxesToDisplay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this [...] still have the
>   AddingNew event set to NewItemAdded()
>   with either definition of
>   BoxesToDisplay?

No, you are totally replacing `_boxesToDisplay` reference. There is no mechanism to transplant eventhandlers.

All I can say is that with the Auto-Imp property you wouldn't need the `-=` as much as there is no chance that something else will still have access to the old instance. But you would still have to attach to the new one.